# Doctrine: remove entity without loading

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to remove an object that is an attribute of another object, but when I do this I get an exception saying “Entity was not found.”

An example of what I mean:

```php
// Foo has a private property, bar, which is an instance of Bar
$foo = $this->get('my_bundle.repository.foo')->find($fooId);
$bar = $foo->getBar();

$entityManager = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$entityManager->remove($bar);
$entityManager->flush();
```

I guess this is because the entity manager didn't load an instance of `Bar` directly, as the following seems to work:

```php
// Foo has a private property, bar, which is an instance of Bar
$foo = $this->get('my_bundle.repository.foo')->find($fooId);
$bar = $this->get('my_bundle.repository.foo')->find($bar->getId());

$entityManager = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$entityManager->remove($bar);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Is there a way to make this work without reloading `$bar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Foo still has Bar as a property when you flush the entity manager. Do

```
$foo->setBar(null);
$entityManager->persist($foo);
```

before you do the flush